# Time difference between two timings if they run more than a day in shell script

Tags: shell

The following are the two logs first line and last line i want to know the time difference between those two logs.

> INFO  02 Oct 2013 02:13:36,200 vert.x-eventloop-thread-1 [2514751586306/entityCrawl] [oiq.whiteboard.CrawlHandler] - Company start
>
> INFO  05 Oct 2013 02:13:36,200 vert.x-eventloop-thread-1 [2514735333378/entityCrawl] [oiq.whiteboard.CrawlHandler] - Company finish [4293663 ms]

I used the Following Program

```
#!/bin/bash
START=$(date --date="$1" +"%s")
ND=$(date --date="$2" +"%s")
DIFFSEC=$(($END-$START))
time=`date +%H:%M:%S -ud @${DIFFSEC}`
echo "$time" | awk -F':'  '{ print $1*3600 + $2*60 + $3 }'
```

But it did not give me Correct time difference Please Give me a program to solve this

Expected Output :

> Started time=02 Oct 2013 02:13:36
>
> Ended time=05 Oct 2013 02:13:36
>
> timediff=72:00:00

Comment: You're just subtracting the number of seconds, why do you expect it to convert into hours automatically? If you want to convert seconds to hours, minutes, and seconds, you have to do the division yourself.

Comment: The Program is giving me in seconds only but when the date is changed then it not showing me the correct time difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` gives you a time of day, not a duration. It's simple enough to turn the diff value into hours, mins, secs, a simple matter of arithmetic.

```
diff=123456
(( hours = diff / 3600 ))
(( mins = (diff - hours*3600) / 60 ))
(( secs = diff % 60 ))
printf "%d:%02d:%02d\n" $hours $mins $secs
```

```
34:17:36
```

Bash even lets you put all the math into a single arithmetic expression, if you want to:

```
(( 
    hours = diff / 3600,
    mins = (diff - hours*3600) / 60,
    secs = diff % 60 
))
```